# The term 'dockerd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: docker, command, docker-daemon

In the [docker document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/protect-access/) `dockerd` command is used but I am getting below error when I try to execute

```
dockerd \
    --tlsverify \
    --tlscacert=ca.pem \
    --tlscert=server-cert.pem \
    --tlskey=server-key.pem \
    -H=0.0.0.0:2376
```

I have docker desktop intalled on Windows 11 Home Edition.

```
dockerd : The term 'dockerd' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ dockerd
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (dockerd:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```